# Why does destructuring an `enum` in Rust catch references, not values?

Tags: rust

With

```
enum Frame {
    RSTACK{v: u8, c: u8},
    // ...
}
```

```
   [...]
      match self {
         Self::RSTACK{v, c} => { ... }
```

I was expecting to get `v: u8` out after destructuring, but it's `v: &u8`.

Why is this?

Comment: `x match { ...` is not valid syntax. What type is `x`?

Comment: @kmdreko True. Corrected. The type is the `Frame` but it's kind of irrelevant for the question itself, I think.

Comment: @akauppi it's quite relevant because of [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html) [demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3b619916744f4b7c3a3f01f3fd2540c)

Comment: @akauppi if the type of `self` is really `Frame` then the type of `v` in the arm is `u8`, I suspect the actual type is `&Frame`. Please add proper [mre]s to your questions, not just some arbitrary snippets.

Comment: @cafce25 Your comment already helped ("if the type of ... is really `Frame`). I am still learning Rust, and genuinly thought the larger context would not matter. I agree about the vitality of minimum code samples, but didn't know whether "it's just supposed to be like that". My bad.